# How to solve the Error in plot.new: figure margins too large in R shiny?

Tags: r

I have a small shiny app, which allow users to download plot with chosen resolution.

But Sometimes, I got the following error: **Error in plot.new: figure margins too large**.

When this happens, the only way is to restart the shiny app, and choose a smaller resolution, which is very inconvenient.

I know `ggsave()` from ggplot2 package can solve this problem, but since I am suing base R plot, I am wondering if there is an element way to bypass this error?

Thanks a lot.

Here is my demo shiny app:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton("download_plot", "Download plot"),
    sliderInput("res", "Select resolition", min = 150, max = 900, value = 300, step = 50)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, xlab = "Weight", ylab = "Miles per gallon")
  })
  
  output$download_plot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("plot", ".png", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      png(file, width = 800, height = 600, res = input$res)
      plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
      dev.off()
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The problem isn't related to Shiny, but to the maximal resolution allowed for the plot. If the resolution (in pixels per inch) is too high, the figure will be so small (heigh in inches = heigh in pixels / resolution) that there is no space left to draw the axes labels. Try for example to open `test.png` after `png('test.png', width = 800, height = 600, res = 300);plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg);dev.off()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you specify `width` and `height` in pixels while modifying resolution in dots per inch, resulting in a picture becoming smaller as you increase resolution.
If resolution is too high, the picture is so small that the axis labels can't be drawn correctly, hence the error message.

In order to keep a constant picture size, you could multiply `width` and `height` by resolution :

```
content = function(file) {
      png(file, width = 800*input$res/300, height = 600*input$res/300, res = input$res)
      plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
      dev.off()
    }
```